# Removing space after \end{enumerate} \end{theorem}

Tags: lists, enumerate, vertical-spacing

I have reviewed posts here addressing the removal of whitespace before a list, using the **enumitem** package, and I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of the whitespace after a list.

Here is a minimal version of my file:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}
Here is a list, and some text before the list.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item (Property 1) 
    \item (Property 2) 
    \item (Property 3) 
\end{enumerate}
Here is some text after the list.
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I realised that the minimal version works perfectly, i.e. there is no space before and after the list. On more careful observation, it seems that the the lists I am having problems with are nested in other environments (theorems). Here is an updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage[ntheorem]{mathtools,empheq}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thref,hyperref,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremheaderfont{\sc}\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremseparator{}
\theoremsymbol{\rule{1ex}{1ex}}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
This is a pretty nice theorem.
\begin{theorem}
Here is a list, and some text before the list.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item (Property 1) 
    \item (Property 2) 
    \item (Property 3) 
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
Here are some remarks after the theorem.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless my eye deceives me, I sse no "extra" space after the enumerate list inside the `theorem` environment, just the usual space after the `theorem` environment itself.

Comment: @murray , thanks for taking the time. Is there a way to customise the space after the theorem enviroment?

Comment: you are using `ntheorem`, this is configured by declaring the `\theorempostskip`; see page 6 of the ntheorem manual. (You should set it before declaring the new theorems.) The default value is `\topsep`.

Comment: Thank you @WillieWong!

Comment: @P.J.: If you use the `thmtools` package instead of `ntheorem`, then when declaring a particular theorem style (or, separately, a particular definition style, etc.) you may include a setting for its `spacebelow` option.

Comment: @murray , thank you very much, professor. I'll look into the thmtools package. Basically I need a way to create hyperlinks for theorems, when I mention them later in arguments.